# Altium: Pour small ground plane inside PWR plane

Tags: altium

I have a layer with a full copper pour connected to 5V. I need to have a small section inside of this that is connected to ground. Is this possible in Altium Designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple areas with different nets a plane layer are common in PCBs, and possible in Altium.
There are two (2) general options to create that, depending on how the layer is set up in Altium.

The layer is defined as a **plane layer** in the PCB stack-up.  In layers like that Altium renders traces as negative - traces are gaps in copper.  If you draw a closed-loop trace, you'll create an island in a plane with a gap around it.  You can assign a net to the island, and it will behave like a plane with that net (vias will connect to it).

The layer is defined as a **routing layer** in the PCB stack-up.  Use polygons to create islands.  If you draw a polygon which covers the entire PCB, then it will be a *de facto* plane.  If you draw a polygon B in the middle of another polygon A with a different net, then Altium will add clearance around polygon B, and it will be an island.

Comment: [Here's an example for the second method.](https://www.flickr.com/photos/46038819@N07/50014299033)  Planes are copper pours in the routing layers.

Comment: If you have multiple pours on a layer, I recommend NOT defining the layer as a plane as this restricts the use of complex rules. It's also harder to edit the islands than using a routing layer.

Comment: @qrk  That's right.  Does Altium even allow to have a polygon pour in a layer that's defined as a plane layer?  I almost always do planes with polygon pours in routing inner layers, because that's more flexible.

Comment: @misk94555 You can't add pours to a plane layer. "Split Planes" is what you described. You draw lines and arcs to isolate copper areas as you mentioned. Double-click on the isolated area to change the net name. Split planes is poorly implemented in Altium, so best to avoid split planes unless the split is very simple and you don't need specific rules on that plane layer.